# parallelize array whith tbb::paralel for

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, intel, tbb

I´m new in IntelTBB and I am trying to parallelize an array of vector. This is the function, in which I pass the array as a pointer.

```
void calculate(map<int,string> &m, vector<order>* ord, auto&k, string &dir){

for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
//here I declare a series of variables

    for(int j=0; j<ord[i][j].size()-1; j++){
        // here I do a series of calculations with the values of
        // the array and I generate one file for each row of the array
        // with this calculations, to do this I declare more variables
     }


}


}
```

I want to parallelize this function so that it can process several rows of the array at the same time. I have tried to do this with parallel_for as follows:

```
void calculate(map<int,string> &m, vector<order>* ord, auto&k, string &dir){

tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0,k),[&](tbb::blocked_range<int>r)
{
for(int i=r.begin();i<r.end();i++){
//here I declare a series of variables

    for(int j=0; j<ord[i][j].size()-1; j++){
        // here I do a series of calculations with the values of
        // the array and I generate one file for each row of the array
        // with these calculations, to do this I declare more variables
     }


});


}
```

This program compile well, but when it is executed, sometimes I obtain a result (generate text file that I need) with wrong calculations, but normally  I obtain an error like this:

TBB Warning : Exact exception propagation is requested by application but the linked library is built without support for it
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tbb::capture_exception'

How can this be done correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: The code that you've shown looks right.  I'm wondering if the "a series of calculations" has some kind of cross-iteration dependence, e.g. a read-write  dependence for some memory location.

Comment: I basically read the values of the array and calculate some areas or others based on these values. Then I generate, for each row, a file with these calculations. In this code I create auxiliar variables to help in calculations. I don´t know if I need to create a mutex object so that two threads do not access the variables at the same time.

Comment: Two threads can safely read a variable at the same time.  But if one reads and the other writes, or both write, then there can be problems.  A simple test (won't catch all possible errors, but will catch a bunch of common ones) is to reverse the iteration order of the serial loop and see if you get the same results.